# what is it called in English a driver who violates the traffic rules?

Tags: word-usage

There are drivers who violate traffic rules. what are they called in English? Is "traffic offender" a right option?

Comment: I don't think there are any terms commonly used for this in the UK. [Michael Winner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Winner) used to openly boast of always having his London chauffeur drive the Rolls Royce down bus lanes, 'cos the fines were chickenfeed to him (and they'd *always* be collected; we've had camera recognition there for years). Anyway, if you're talking about *drivers who violate traffic rules*, that would be *every* driver in the UK (they may never have been ***caught and fined***, but every driver has broken at least some of the rules at some time).

Comment: What we don't like are ***road hogs***, who drive badly, erratically, etc., and "push" other drivers around.

Comment: They're  called normal drivers. Everybody violates traffic rules. Can you provide more context? What kind of traffic rules? There are drunk drivers and people with road rage and people who drive dangerously and people who violate the rules all the time but never get caught, and people who get caught and even thrown in jail...............

Comment: well, maybe all of them. I am translating a questionnaire from Persian into English regarding the human factors in car accidents. The participants who answer it are those drivers who violate traffic rules and may cause accidents, their cars may be seized by police, so on. Now I doubt whether I can use "traffic offender" or "offender driver" for these participants

Comment: @morteza The driver's overall behavior may be that of an *aggressive driver*, or a *reckless driver*, but you can be aggressive without technically violating traffic laws, and as noted, the vast majority of people will violate a minor law (e.g. not stopping completely at a stop sign, speeding a few kph over the posted limit) without qualifying as aggressive or reckless.

Comment: In support of what @choster says, we actually have signs in the US that read  "Beware of Aggressive Drivers". https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1213&bih=758&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=aggressive+drivers+roadsign&oq=aggressive+drivers+roadsign&gs_l=img.3...17283.21457.0.21742.12.12.0.0.0.0.100.721.11j1.12.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.3.196...0j0i24j0i30.n27qpUZBbdQ#imgrc=LNZPm48PqOxFrM%3A  Though I tend to think it's impossible to be an aggressive driver without violating some traffic law (speeding, tailgating, failing to use turn signals properly, passing on the wrong side, etc)

Comment: I have never seen a *beware of aggressive drivers* sign in my life. I haven't driven in all 50 states but I have in quite a few...

Comment: Maybe you were texting when you passed one?

Comment: @AlanCarmack I see signs which are both [warning about](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jeffs4653/5997635507) aggressive drivers and [warnings to](https://www.flickr.com/photos/mrfrosted/1321410755) aggressive drivers all around the inland Mid-Atlantic.

Comment: Maybe I just live where all drivers are aggressive  so it's no big deal... *Cover me, I'm fixing to/about to change lanes*

Comment: @morteza Until this moment, I had no idea that police authorities in Iran can sieze the vehicles of traffic offenders! Here, traffic offenses are minor and routine, and usually result only in a fine. A vehicle can only be impounded if it is implicated in a non-traffic-related offense - a real crime, in other words. One more reason to be thankful for my good fortune in living where I do.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Police can seize cars here in the UK [for a number of traffic and road offences](https://www.gov.uk/stopped-by-police-while-driving-your-rights/when-the-police-can-seize-your-vehicle): no insurance, no licence, illegally parked, etc.

Comment: @LMS Yet _another_ reason to be thankful for my good fortune in living where I do! But there is no place on earth where I would rather have breakfast than dear Blighty.

Answer (score 2):

"Traffic offender" would be a good choice of phrase here, and it's even one used by some laws:

> **322.264 "Habitual traffic offender" defined.**
>   A "habitual traffic offender" is any person whose record, as maintained by
>   the Department of Highway Safety and Motor Vehicles, shows that such person
>   has accumulated the specified number of convictions for offenses described
>   in subsection (1) or subsection (2) within a 5-year period: ...
>
> *[Title XXIII (Motor Vehicles), Chapter 322 (Driver Licenses), 2016 Florida Statutes](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0300-0399/0322/Sections/0322.264.html)*

However, in my experience it is generally more common to refer to a traffic offender by using a term derived from the specific offence they have committed. For example:

> A drunk (or drug) driver. *(also **drink driver**)*
>   A speeder.
>   A dangerous/careless driver.
>   A hit-and-runner.

Some offences don't have terms associated with them. In that case, it is generally just said which offence the person committed:

> He ran a red light.
>   *Not stopping at traffic lights on red.*

Comment: "drink driver" is a UK term, not a US term.

Answer (score 2):

If, in the context of your questionnaire, it is clear that you are speaking strictly about traffic and traffic violations,  then it might be sufficient to refer to people who break the traffic laws as *offenders* or *violators*.

Although, these terms might have specific legal definitions, in terms of plain language, *traffic offender* seems fine. Similarly, I also like

> **traffic violator**

[image]

To be safe, I don't see a problem with saying *traffic law offender* or *traffic law violator*, for example.